# Access the inner DIV with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

If I have the following HTML:

```
<tr class="class">
    <td>
       <div>
       </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How can I access the div with JavaScript knowing that all the styles on the div are applied like this: `.class td div { ... }` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For modern browsers [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector) is the way to go:

```
var html = document.querySelector(".class td div").innerHTML;
```

For accessing multiple elements you can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".class td div");
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    // elements[i]. ...
}
```

Comment: This seems to resolve it. Thank you for your help (edit+answer)

Comment: @Tbi45 But pay attention that the described approach won't work in IE<8. Then such methods as [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementById) or [`element.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) must be applied.